# What is the meaning of a tattoo I got in college? (Characters identified: 靜平)

Tags: character-identification

What is the meaning of this tattoo? Got it in college. I've always been worried it doesn’t say what I thought...

[image: Image of 靜平 tattoo]

I think it means serenity and peace; I was a young guy and at the time was going through some tough stuff. It's a turning point tattoo.

Comment: Nothing offensive, just shows whoever came up with this tattoo is not a native Chinese speaker... although it is not a common Chinese phrase, we can guess what you tried to express. The full translation of "Serenity and Peace" is "寧靜平和" so 靜平 is kind of passable shorthand for that.

Comment: Thank you. It means a lot you took the time to respond. Very grateful for the clarity. Not offended at all. Passable but not accurate. Just want to make sure I am being respectful by having it as well.

Comment: You could, if you like, even adopt it as your "Chinese" name, though if you are male, it may "sound" a bit "feminine" :)

Answer (score 2):

The tattoo contains these two words, 靜(quiet, steady) and 平(level, peaceful) that, if read separately, do possesses the meanings you are seeking, however, it is meaningless when the two words are read in sequence as shown - "靜平", rather, the sequence of the words shall be reversed to form the traditional Chinese lexis - "平靜", which possesses the same meanings of the words, 靜 and 平 described above.

Comment: read bottom to top, the original meaning was probably: chill

Comment: It'll be interesting to know exactly where the tattoo is located?